# ValueError at /app/recomment/1/

Tags: python, django

I got an error,ValueError at /app/recomment/1/
Cannot assign "": "ReComment.target" must be a "POST" instance.The error is happened when I put Recomment button.I wanna make a page which is shown comment&recomment.I wrote codes 
in models.py

```
class POST(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    target = models.ForeignKey(POST, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)


class ReComment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    target = models.ForeignKey(POST, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

I cannot understand the error message's meaning that is I should put POST into obj.target = comment in place of comment in views.py.The variable of comment is send via POST,so I think this is POST instance.I cannot understand the difference of POST instance and normal instance.What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?

Comment: Where is your `POST` model?

Comment: @heemayl I updated my models.py

Comment: You've really confused yourself by using "POST" for the name of the model. If you called it "Post" you would not be confused with the request.POST.

Comment: if you want create item or object or somthing like ! you must use correct base view.  Use createView not view. your views class ReCommentCreateView(generic.View) and ... must inherit create view not view e.g: ReCommentCreateView(CreateView)

Comment: @DanielRoseman So is  the error messages' POST the model of POST?

Comment: @rakwen I rewrote `class CommentCreateView(CreateView):` & `class ReCommentCreateView(CreateView):`,but same error happens.If u know something, please help me

Comment: ForeignKey  `target` in ReComment model must be of `Comment` model.

Comment: Well, yes. The target field on the ReComment model points to POST, not Comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this and check that to not forget anything.

```
   class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
   model = POST <<<<-------- error give true model here
   template_name = 'detail.html'
```